# How to detect in iOS wether a user has secured device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can i detect in iOS swift or objective-c wether user device is secured by password or touchID?

Im trying to not let open app if user didnt secure his device.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928591/see-if-touch-id-is-enabled-on-iphone-5s

Comment: You can't directly tell about pin code without touch-id, but i can't imagine any times you really need to know that